# How To Get ColumnIndex In XAML to apply style too

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ColumnIndex" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I remembered I Was able to accomplish this with code similar to this but can't remember how I did it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting `"ColumnIndex"` which does not exist in `DataGridCell` class.

Creating column definitions makes adding a style to the second column only much easier to do rather than relying on a trigger.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn />
            <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This sounds right but I'm getting "column is not supported in a windows presentation foundation project" am I missing a namespace in my app.xaml file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want the text color of the cells in column 2 to be red.

Here is your style...

```
    <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
```

Then for the column that you want to style...

```
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" CellStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Technically this is a correct way of doing it but doesn't really apply to me since I'm trying to do it by using the column index.